# Why am I getting false?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
const parent = document.querySelector(".parent");

if (parent.classList.contains("child")) {
  console.log(true);
} else {
  console.log(false);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

When I try to check if 'parent' has a 'child' class, I get false, but why?

I used to work with contains() and everything worked out fine, but at one point I got false data. Why, can you help me with this? Point out my mistakes in the code.

Comment: The parent does NOT have a class of `child`. Are you trying to check if the parent contains an element with the class child?

Comment: Seem like you're confusing things. Your code checks if `<div class="parent">` has a class `child`. It doesn't. What you wanted to do is check if any of the **children** of `parent` have class `child`

Comment: The `classList` of `parent` does not contain the `child` class. Why do you think it should return anything else? If you need to know if any element with class `parent` has any child elements with a specific class `child`, why not just query for it explicitly? `document.querySelectorAll('.parent .child').length > 0`

Comment: Try: **if(parent.querySelector(".child"))** that will check to see if .child is a child of parent.

Answer (score 3):

> When I try to check if 'parent' has a 'child' class, I get false, but why?

Because it doesn't have that class:

```
<div class="parent">
```

It does *contain an element* which has that class.  If that's what you're looking to test, you can select *that* element and check if the result is `null`.  For example:

```js
const childOfParent = document.querySelector(".parent .child");

if (childOfParent) {
  console.log(true);
} else {
  console.log(false);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Or, if you already have the `parent` object, you can select the child specifically from that element:

```js
const parent = document.querySelector(".parent");
const child = parent.querySelector(".child");

if (child) {
  console.log(true);
} else {
  console.log(false);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your parent container doesn't have the child class.
The child of the parent has the class.

Either put the class `child` on the parent or use for example sth like this:
`if(parent.getElementsByClassName('child')[0]) {}`

Answer (score 0):

The `parent.classList` is an array with classes of the matched element itself, not is children.

You can use it's `.children` property to access it's direct ancestors

```js
const parent = document.querySelector(".parent");
const children = Array.from(parent.children);

console.log(
  children.some(child => child.classList.contains("child"))
);
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `classList` on the `.parent` (which is incorrect), you can query for a nested `.child`:

```js
const parent = document.querySelector('.parent');

if (parent.querySelector('.child') !== null) {
  console.log(true);
} else {
  console.log(false);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `parent.querySelector('.child') !== undefined` is always going to be `true`.

Comment: @Unmitigated changed to `null` , thanks.